# a problem using gmp library in QT under win xP SP2

Tags: c++, qt, gmp

I have a problem using the GMP library in a Qt project under Windows XP SP2.

When I run my Qt application, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. When the application crashes, it display a warning with the message "Microsoft Visual C++ runtime Library run time error" or hangs for a few minutes. Sometimes it works (and there is no error)

Here are some specifics:

i used QT ver 4.3.2 (open source)
compiler: mingw32 ver : GNU Make 3.80
          GCC         : 3.4.5 (mingw special) 
          G++         : 3.4.5 (mingw special)
gmp 4.3.2
my cpu type :x86 family

I had compiled the GMP library successfully like this using MSYS 1.0.11:

> ./configure --prefix=/gmp/install --enable-cxx
>
> make
>
> make install

Here are my Qt pro.file contents :

```
..
..
INCLUDEPATH += C:/LIBGMP
LIBS += -LC:/LIBGMP -lgmpxx -lgmp
```

Here is a part of my application function in Qt using GMP library :

```
QString gmptambah(QString angka1 ,QString angka2,int angkapresisi) const
 {

  mpf_set_default_prec(angkapresisi); 

  mpf_t x,y,z;

  mpf_init (x); 
         mpf_init (y); 
         mpf_init (z);

        QByteArray encodedString1=angka1.toAscii ();
        const char *x1= encodedString1.constData ();

 QByteArray encodedString2=angka2.toAscii ();
        const char *y1= encodedString2.constData ();

  mpf_set_str (x,x1,10);

  mpf_set_str (y,y1,10);

  mpf_add (z,y,x);

  mp_exp_t exponent ;

  mpf_class nilaiz(z);
  nilaiz.set_prec(angkapresisi);

  QString hasil((nilaiz.get_str(exponent, 10, 0)).c_str()); // this is my problem

  long int exp=(exponent);

  if(exp>=0)
  {
   if(hasil.at(0)!='-' && exp==0)
   {
           hasil.insert(0,"0"); exp++;
   }
   else if(hasil.at(0)=='-' && exp==0)
   {
           hasil.insert(1,"0");

    exp=exp+2;
   }
   else if(hasil.at(0)=='-' && exp>=1)
   {           
    exp=exp+1;
   }

   hasil.insert(exp,".");

   hasil.replace(QString(" "), QString("0"));

   QStringList hasiltmp;

   hasiltmp=hasil.split(".");

   if(hasiltmp.size()==1) hasil.append("0");
   else if(hasiltmp.size()==2)
   {
           if(hasiltmp.at(1)=="")hasil.append("0");
   }

  }
  else
  {
          if(hasil.at(0)!='-') for(int i=0;i<qAbs(exp);i++)hasil.insert(0,"0");
   else for(int i=0;i<qAbs(exp);i++)hasil.insert(1,"0");

   if(hasil.at(0)!='-') hasil.insert(0,"0.");
   else hasil.insert(1,"0.");

  }

  mpf_clear (x);
         mpf_clear (y);
         mpf_clear (z);

  x1=0; y1=0;

  return pembulatan(hasil);

 }
```

After tracing the problem, I found that my problem is located at `nilaiz.get_str(exponent, 10, 0)` function which called the `mpf_get_str` function in `gmpxx.h`

When I remove it from my application (without calling the `nilaiz.get_str(exponent, 10, 0)` function), the application runs well without errors.

But I need that function to convert `mpf_t z` to `QString` (string in Qt or `char *`).

Why does this happen? What should I do next? Or am I missing something when I compile the GMP library or should I add an xtra option when I configure GMP or there is a bug using that function?

I need help or suggestions. Thank you!

Best regards

aansd

Comment: Can you point exactly what error occurs in runtime? An assertion is triggered?

Comment: the error is it display a warning with the message "Microsoft Visual C++ runtime Library run time error" or hang a few minutes, but some time it can work well ( there is nothing error) . i assume that problem is using mpf_get_str function in gmpxx.h. Without using that function my application work well

Comment: [rant] Please ensure you're using correct grammar (starting with capitalization and punctuation). I understand your first language isn't English (I'm not a native English speaker), but this is not some teenage forum where it's cool to talk in an MSN-like language. [/rant]. For the rest, nice question, with pretty much all the info one would need to solve it!